# Can I make Cypress run the beta version of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

We want to test our Angular Application with the beta version of chrome Version 80.0.3987.78 (Official Build) beta (64-bit). I also have on my machine Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (32-bit). Is there a way I can make Cypress run the beta version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just download the specified version from [chromium.cypress.io](https://chromium.cypress.io/).

Then you have two options:

- Place the executable in the expected path with the expected binary name - more info [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Launching-browsers)
- Launch Cypress specifying a path to the binary. Example with path `/usr/bin/chromium`:

  - `cypress run --browser /usr/bin/chromium` or
  - `cypress open --browser /usr/bin/chromium`

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I did get it to work another way, I downloaded the beta and changed the path to be where chrome normally is and that worked. There were some worries the beta was going to break Angular reactive forms and I need to quickly prove my app was still working. I appreciate you taking the time to add an answer

Comment: Thank you. Glad to know that you were able to solve the problem.